# Fill listbox with data in Silverlight, which way to go?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0

ouch, i've been doing asp.net for a few years now, and for a year asp.net mvc, and now: silverlight.
Feel like a newbee again.

I want to fill a listbox with dataitems, fair enough?
I want to show an imagename and an image.

This is what i've seen so far:
create a datasource with dummy data, and bind the collection to the listbox (designtime). Beldn creates a datatemplate, and the dummy data is shown. But then what, create a new datasource at runtime with the real data and bind that one?

Or two: use MVVM. Create an object with a property of type ObservableCollection and let the listbox and the property co-operate. Only heard of this, so don't know how to implement it :)

Or third: Type it all in code behind: get the data, create the listboxitems, add them to the listbox (maybe hardcode the layout too, no XAML needed)

I must say the third option is the easy one because that sounds familiar, and the other two are so much different from my perspective, that i don't have a clue where to start.

I want to add: i've seen a few silverlight video's and they were all done in Blend, so the first one i have seen in Blend, the second one i've read about and the third is what i know how to do.

Long story, if you can give me a hand, i'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use option two--MVVM is the way to go.
the basic steps are like this:
1) define your class, deriving from INotifyPropertyChanged

```
public class MyImage : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string ImagePath { ... }
    public bool IsChecked { ... }       
}
```

2) define your data template for the class so that the ListBox knows how to display the items

```
<ListBox>
   <ListBox.temTemplate>
      <Setter.Value>
         <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
              <CheckBox Source="{Binding IsChecked}"/>
              <Image Source="{Binding Name}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
     </Setter.Value>
   </Setter>
</ListBox>
```

4) make an observable collection and fill it with instances of your class

```
public class DataModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ObservableCollection<MyImage> MyItems{...}
}
....
public class MyWindow : Page
{
    public MyWindow ()
    {
        this.DataContext = new DataModel( ); 
    }
}
```

5) bind the ItemsSource property of the list box to the collection

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}>
   <ListBox.temTemplate>
      <Setter.Value>
         <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
              <CheckBox Source="{Binding IsChecked}"/>
              <Image Source="{Binding Name}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
     </Setter.Value>
   </Setter>
</ListBox>
```

you should [check out this tutorial on ScottGu's Blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/pages/silverlight-2-end-to-end-tutorial-building-a-digg-search-client.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, i'm going to try that. The Scott doesn't use the mvvm does he? he just binds the data to the grid in code behind?

Comment: By the way, where do i declare my viewmodel variable so that it is available in the databinding window?

Comment: probabably the easist would be to set the datacontext property of the window to your viewmodel object.  then, when you databind, you only have to set the Path property.

Comment: Thanks very much for this tutorial, i'm finally getting a start with the mvvm!

Comment: This leaves me with the question however, if i do use the 'datasource with dummy data' solution, is that only for prototype, or do i have to decorate my solution with 'if in designermode do this, otherwise do that' code?

Comment: you CAN do that, but you dont have to.  there are methods to detect if you are in design mode and then, if you are, you can fill with dummy, or test, data.  if you check http://blogs.msdn.com/delay/archive/2009/02/26/designerproperties-getisindesignmode-forrealz-how-to-reliably-detect-silverlight-design-mode-in-blend-and-visual-studio.aspx you fill find code for detecting design mode